# Oracle SQL: Take a String and turn into a Logical Table?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g

I'm looking for some advice when working with a column value which is a string (varchar(4000)) containing comments. I have to perform an extract based on Dates however I have no timestamps other than a timestamp in the string. I need to extract all comments that have been created within the past 6 months. I've been playing with regexp_SUBSTR, regexp_INSTR but due to limitations on 10g I'm not able to use regexp_count which is making life difficult.

The String would look like this;

```
LOCKED ENTITY: ACCOUNT
LOCKED BY USER: ops
LOCKED AT: 31/05/2004 11:47
CUST NOTES: <Please enter explanation here>
Customer notes are entered here.

UNLOCKED ENTITY: ACCOUNT
UNLOCKED BY USER: ops
UNLOCKED AT: 31/05/2004 11:49
UNLOCK NOTES: <Please enter explanation here>
Test

LOCKED ENTITY: USER
LOCKED BY USER: ops
LOCKED AT: 31/05/2004 11:50
LOCK NOTES: <Please enter explanation here>
Test

UNLOCKED ENTITY: USER
UNLOCKED BY USER: ops
UNLOCKED AT: 24/08/2009 16:47
UNLOCKED NOTES: <Please enter explanation here>
```

Thankfully the Pieces of data are labelled however I need to extract all 'blocks' above individually so essentially have an ID and 4 records. The ID is another column of this table.

The problem I have is that although the example above shows 4 blocks I could have some with many more or less, there is no definitive number to work with. I've attempted using CONNECT BY and REGECP_COUNT to run through all occurrences but I get no results and regexp_count is 11g onwards.

Ideally I'd like to end up with something looking like this;

```
ID       ENTITY                          ACTION                     DATE                          LOCK_NOTES
-------  ------------------------------- -------------------------- ----------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
11652907 LOCKED ENTITY: ACCOUNT          LOCKED BY USER: OPS        LOCKED AT: 11/06/2004 09:11   LOCK NOTES: ACCT Locked
11652907 LOCKED ENTITY: USER             LOCKED BY USER: OPS        LOCKED AT: 11/06/2004 09:58   LOCK NOTES: User Locked
11652907 UNLOCKED ENTITY: USER           UNLOCKED BY USER: OPS      UNLOCKED AT: 11/06/2004 20:05 UNLOCK NOTES: User now aware.
```

Which I'd then be able to query based on Date and extract the relevant records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr(str,'^.*+$',1,level,'m')` to extract each row along with `level` pseoducolumn within `select..connect by level` structure to determine row numbers, and group by each six rows :

```
with tab as
(
select regexp_substr(str,'^.*+$',1,level,'m') as str, level as rn
  from tab0
connect by level <= instr(str,chr(10))+1
)
select max(case when mod(rn,6)=1 then str end) as "ENTITY",
       max(case when mod(rn,6)=2 then str end) as "ACTION",
       max(case when mod(rn,6)=3 then str end) as "DATE",
       max(case when mod(rn,6)=4 then str end) as "LOCK_NOTES"
  from tab
 group by ceil(rn/6);
```

where `Chr(10)` is the line feed character

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5fa2703e6fd62fda0dc57488db7c7303)</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately it's 10g so regexp_count isn't an option :(

Comment: well, replace with `instr` @user7329642

Comment: Hi, I'm losing the will with this :( Due to the limitations with 10g I've copied the table across to an 11g instance. 
When using "connect by level <= instr(str,chr(10))+1" it complains with;

ORA-00904: "STR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 27

It makes no sense as there is no %s, unless it's a search function within the regexp? Could you let me know the previous suggestion where connect by regexp_count? Now that I'm on 11g I can try that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the name of your column, which I called as `str`, defined by varchar(4000). So, you should replace str with your real column name @user7329642 .

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it was that causing the error, I've tweaked a bit and I think i've got it working;


select id,regexp_substr(VALUE,'^.*+$',1,level,'m') as str, level as rn
  from tab1 
connect by level <= instr(VALUE,chr(10))+1 

However I'm also returning a number of null value rows, I'm just trying to find out how to shoehorn NOT NULL into the connect by. (apologies, using the connect by and regexp is new to me so still trying to understand the syntax).

Comment: After finally getting the query to work with some sample test data it became clear that I had to change tact due some issues with the data format resulting in columns being populated with incorrect values, this was a data issue more than a query issue. I've since started again with different logic and although it works perfectly against a table with a handful of records when I run this against a table with thousands (tens of thousands) it runs indefinitely. The execution plan is showing a full table scan which is to be expected but the table isn't exactly huge.

Comment: Here is what I'm using now, are there any issues that would explain this? Any comments on tweaks?

select
  id,
  substr(regexp_substr(VALUE,'^LOCKED BY USER: +(.*)',1,level,'m'),17) as LOCKUSER,
  substr(regexp_substr(VALUE,'^LOCKED ENTITY: +(.*)',1,level,'m'),16) as LOCKED_ENTITY,
  TO_DATE(LTRIM(regexp_substr(VALUE,'^LOCKED AT: ([[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}\.?)',1,level,'m'),'LOCKED AT: '),'DD/MM/YYYY') as Dates_Locked,
  substr(regexp_substr(VALUE,'^LOCK NOTES: +(.*)',1,level,'m'),13) as LOCK_NOTES,
  'LOCK' as ACTION

Comment: from TAB
 where regexp_substr(VALUE,'^LOCK NOTES: +(.*)',1,level,'m') IS NOT NULL
 AND TO_DATE(LTRIM(regexp_substr(VALUE,'LOCKED AT: ([[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}\.?)',1,level,'m'),'LOCKED AT: '),'DD/MM/YYYY') >= (SYSDATE -365)
connect by level <= regexp_count(VALUE,CHR(10)||CHR(13));

Comment: [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea9d82e559b8797146596e2209139045) query returns nothing. Btw, What's the problem with my solution ? @user7329642

Comment: I've added the query which I wrote, I've not done this with the Test data you provided in the demo in mind sorry. Also it may not return the sample record based on the date predicate only returning anything within the past year. There is nothing wrong with you solution, but unfortunately due to data issues it resulted throwing off the columns so I decided i couldn't rely on using the CHR(10) as an anchor and had to explicity search and substring each of the notes i.e "LOCKED ENTITY as it's own column based on a search for the exact string.

Comment: Just checked on the example and can confirm if you change the date predicate to <= it returns the record. Cheers

Comment: that case returns [only one row](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f6f930b9748a0c04d0f25855b89b2574) @user7329642

Comment: I believe the test data on dB fiddle only consists of a single record